# How to start email if I am not sure other party remembers me?

Tags: american-english, email

I had a contact with a person a long ago. If I want to contact with him now, is it okay to write something like 'I am not sure if you remember me, we met ....'? Or you will suggest other ways which sound milder?

Comment: You may not remember me, but we met....

Comment: @KristinaLopez sorry if this question is off-topic here. Can you please suggest any relevant group for this kind of queries?

Comment: There are good suggestions here (our community is usually helpful that way) but it might also be a good question for http://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should feel comfortable dropping the "I'm not sure" portion.

In my experience, I jump right in with "We met at..." plus an interesting tidbit that might remind them of the encounter. This approach is nice and non-commital, it doesn't overtly state that you suspect they've forgotten you, but makes sure they have the info they need.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. If you never say anything that accuses them of forgetting, you'll be in the best possible situation. To add, using "We met at..." also makes the encounter seem a bit more casual, putting less pressure on the person to feel like they *should* remember.

Comment: Thank you for this, the inherent accusation of forgetfulness hadn't occurred to me with "not sure if you remember me" before. However, I do think this is more of a British English thing, as it's also self-deprecating, in that it's also saying "I do not consider myself important enough that you would consume energy storing me in your brain.".